# You have an error in your SQL syntax, check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax '(TO_BASE64(RANDOM_BYTES(16)

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

trying to import sql file in phpmyadmin and i am getting this error:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
  `id` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL  DEFAULT (TO_BASE64(RANDOM_BYTES(16))),
  `name` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `UNIQUE_name` UNIQUE (`name`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4;

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(TO_BASE64(RANDOM_BYTES(16))),
  `name` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` DA' at line 2
```

mysql Server version: 5.7.35 - MySQL Community Server (GPL),
Protocol version: 10,
PHP version: 7.4.24

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not support expressions in the `DEFAULT` clause of a column until version 8.0.13. You will have to upgrade your version of MySQL Server to use this feature.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html#data-type-defaults-explicit